# Menu not working very well on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have this HTML code :

```
<ul class="navigation-links">
    <li class="link-item">
        <img src="images/new-menu/menu-item_04.png" width="150" height="41" alt="" />
        <div style="display: none" class="sub-menu">
            <div class="sub-col">
                <img src="images/new-menu/home.png" width="46" height="14" alt="" />
                <ul>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-col">
                <img src="images/new-menu/home.png" width="46" height="14" alt="" />
                <ul>
                     <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-col">
                <img src="images/new-menu/sataer.png" width="124" height="17" alt="" />
                <ul>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="link-item">
        <img src="images/new-menu/menu-item_03.png" width="154" height="41" alt="" />
        <div style="display:none" class="sub-menu index-menu-col2">
            <div class="sub-col">
                <img src="images/new-menu/decor.png" width="53" height="15" alt="" />
                <ul>
                  <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
            <div class="sub-col">
                <img src="images/new-menu/acc.png" width="94" height="15" alt="" />
                <ul>
                  <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
            <div class="sub-col">
                <img src="images/new-menu/out-decor.png" width="120" height="17" alt="" />
                <ul>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="link-item">
        <img src="images/new-menu/menu-item_02.png" width="152" height="41" alt="" />
        <div style="display: none" class="sub-menu index-menu-col3">
            <div class="sub-col">
                <img src="images/new-menu/lighting.png" width="35" height="16" alt="" />
                <ul>
                  <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
            <div class="sub-col">
                <img src="images/new-menu/electric.png" width="106" height="19" alt="" />
                <ul>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="link-item"><img src="images/new-menu/menu-item_01.png" width="151" height="41" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

and this JavaScript code :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(".link-item").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideDown("slow");
});
$(".link-item").mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideUp("fast");
});
```

When I open this page on Firefox and try one of these menus, it will act very strangely. and the pointed menu will slide down and slide up continually.

[DEMO PAGE](http://www.mfrsht.com/demo/demo.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some "empty" area right under your links that is causing the menu to go up and down. You could try moving the menu up so that that empty area isn't moused over, which is causing the "mouseleave" function to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you only provided one function `hover()` this will then be executed on both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. You should give it two functions, one for each event. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".link-item").hover(
        function(e) { $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideDown("slow"); },
        function(e) { $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideUp("fast"); }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well, yes. the hover function takes two arguments, one for 'mouse in' the other for 'mouse out' but you put the mouse out outside the hover. Try it more like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".link-item").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideDown("slow");
  },
  function(e) {
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideUp("fast");
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".link-item").mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").stop().slideDown("slow");
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").stop().slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the animation queue build up, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(".link-item").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").stop().slideDown("slow");
});
$(".link-item").mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").stop().slideUp("fast");
});
```